# tMongoDBbulkLoad is not available to download in talend exchange

Tags: excel, mongodb, talend, data-transfer-objects, database

I have 1 million data and I have to transfer it from excel to mongodb. It is throwing heapspace error. How can I perform this job in Talend tool? I have searched for tMongoDBbulkload and it is not available to download.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have this component on Talend Exchange. This component is a part of Talend Open Studio for BigData (>=5.4), just make sure you are using this studio, and not Talend Open Studio Data Integration.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Talend Open Studio for ESB. Is any other way to handle the huge data in this tool?